# htaccess+modrewrite issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want that every user has a profile-url like this:

```
www.example.com/username
```

I have created this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([^/]+) profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

but I get error with the css and js files.

what I have to write in the htaccess ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should in general exclude all real files and directories, as this will handle css/js/images/whatever else you want to serve:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Exclue js and css with `RewriteCond`.I think this should do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! \.(js|css)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ([^/]+) profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

If you have images as well, add their extensions

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! \.(js|css|jpg|gif|ico|png|whatever)$ [NC]
```